# What is the difference between these two variable assignments in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

What is the difference between these two assignments? A inherits from Base.

```
Base b = new A();
A c = new A();
```

I don't understand why this works, if the second is declared as type A.

```
List<Base> vals = new List<Base>();
values.Add(b);
values.Add(c);
```

What should I lookup to understand this more?

Comment: A inherits Base. So c implements base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance constitutes an *is a* relation: if `A` inherits `Base`, it means that `A` can go wherever `Base` is allowed to go. This is precisely what your code snippet is showing: you can add an instance of `A`, a subclass of `Base` to a `List<Base>` where *any* subclass of `Base` can go.

Answer (score 1):

This is because inheritance is transitive. [As MSDN puts it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx):

> If ClassC is derived from ClassB, and ClassB is derived from ClassA, ClassC inherits the members declared in ClassB and ClassA.

So in your case, since `A` inherits from `Base`, `A` "is-a" `Base` and can therefore be added to a `List<Base>`; every element of that list will be a `Base`.

Comment: I don't see how transitivity plays into this at all, as there are only two classes we're concerned with here: `Base` and `A`.  If there were a third `B : A` and we were wondering why it could be used as a `Base` just like an `A` can, then transitivity is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are clear for me. Because in the first, we have a primitive object Base that is beeing instanced like one specialization. And in the second one, A is beeing instanced like its own type. What you have to remember is that the A type is a Base type, too. This feature is named polymorphism.
You can read something more in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 0):

when you add C to vals,the compiler automatically cast c to Base
In OOP -> casting from child to parrent => it's OK

Answer (score 0):

```
Base b = new A();
```

Since A implement Base this is valid.

b will only have the properties and methods of Base.

But the difference is you can cast b to A and then use the properties and methods of A.

Answer (score 0):

These questions on inheritance are fundamental to C# and indeed any Object Orientated Language.
You should start with a good book  [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework, Sixth Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781430242338)
Or some free online tutorials like [Microsoft C# tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
or here [c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362)  They are everywhere....
If you are serious about learning and like instructional videos. 
See www.pluralsight.com  for about 30$ / mth you have some great videos by experts.
For 50$/mth you can download the exercises.

Back to your question.  Ill swap A and B around

```
//Base Class A is Animal.  Class B might be a Bird. 
Animal A = new bird();   // but A has visibility of or can access the features common to all animals Ie access a bird but with a narrower view.
Bird C  = new Bird() ; works for the obvious reason. 

but thats just the beginning...
```

You need to consider abstract and virtual classes and properties.
Overriding properties.
And since your example has a list you may even run into COVARIANCE questions.

Infact jump in the deep end... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee672314
Covariance and Contravariance.  Just to get a taste.

Having recently (in the last 12mths) learnt c#, i would recommend if you are serious, work your way through a book like suggested above, or the video courses.
If you search you will find plenty of info on c# questions.

If yours is a casual interest, well I dont know what to suggest.